# Move org-mode child to be sibling of parent?

Tags: org-mode

Suppose we have

```
* Parent1
** Child1
```

and that our point is at `Child1`. Is there a way to programmatically move `Child1` to be a sibling above `Parent1`, as follows:

```
* Child1
* Parent1
```

?

**EDIT:** The algorithm proposed in the comments fails when centered on `Child1` (since it takes `Child2` along with it):

```
* Parent
** Child1
*** Subchild
** Child2
```

Comment: Maybe this is it(?) - Adjust keybind:
(global-set-key (kbd "M-P") 
 (lambda () (interactive) (org-shiftmetaleft) (org-move-subtree-up)))

Comment: @kai-dj: There are cases where that fails but it does get us closer :)

Comment: What cases you imagine it to fail?

Comment: ok - ye, did not see that ^^ well there must be a way to move the item to bottom of current hierarchy – and then do (org-shiftmetaleft) (org-move-subtree-up)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't fail your usecase, I hope (adjust keybind etc.):

```
(global-set-key (kbd "M-P")
        (lambda ()
          (interactive)
          (condition-case nil
              (while t (org-move-subtree-down))
            (error nil))
          (org-shiftmetaleft)
          (org-move-subtree-up)))
```